# group_by function is converting dataframe to tibble

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse, tibble

I was recently struggling with some code where I used group_by() and then tried to run st_as_sf(). My code wasn't working when previously I had no issues. I discovered that group_by() was converting my dataframe to a tibble and st_as_sf won't work with a tibble. I've had peers run the same code and the conversion from DF to tibble did not occur for them.  Is this something that's happening because of a new update? Has any one else noticed this happening with group_by()? R version 4.0.0 Rstudio version 1.3.959

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow. It’s a good idea to include the code you have tried so that it is easier to help you. Have a look at [mre] and [ask]

Comment: also useful to know `packageVersion("tibble")`, `packageVersion("dplyr")`

Answer (score 1):

This does seem true, at least with a development version of `dplyr`.

```
dd <- data.frame(x=rep(1:4,each=5), y=rnorm(20))
library(dplyr)
str(dd %>% group_by(x) %>% ungroup())
## tibble [20 × 2] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
##  $ x: int [1:20] 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 ...
##  $ y: num [1:20] -0.708 0.976 -1.051 -0.97 -0.225 ...
```

`packageVersion("dplyr")` is 0.8.99.9002.

I can't speak for how this behaved in previous versions. You could always add an `as.data.frame()` at the end of your pipeline ...

Comment: Thanks - I did end up adding as.data.frame() at the end. I don't know what previous versions were like either. You tend to not keep track of things when they're working properly...